# how to check whether a string A is contained into a longer string B for any combination of upper/lower character

Tags: python, string, character

I'm looking for a function in Python that checks whether a string A is contained in a string B for any combination of upper/lower characters of both strings.

Example:

```
a = 'uaUa'
b = 'this is a longer string containing uaua'
```

`checkString (a, b)`   returns `True` because a is contained in b.

Comment: A form of this question has been asked many times so I can going to vote to close it search for substring matching - I will note that a.lower() and b.lower() will help

Comment: ups sorry.
I made a quick search but I couldn't find anything. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def checkString(a, b):
    return a.lower() in b.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'uaUa' 
>>> b = 'this is a longer string containing uaua'
>>> print bool( re.search(a, b, re.IGNORECASE) )
True
```

Comment: why use regular expressions for something this simple?

Comment: actually I thought about using reg expressions but I didn't know the function bool() and IGNORECASE. superquick! thanks :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Happy parsing!

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert both strings to lowercase (for instance) with the ".lower()" method, and then use the standard find methods of Python's string functionalities.